# Grails sorting asList() , sort()

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to sort the result here my code:

```
    def games = Game.withCriteria() { 
                    eq('season', currentSeason) 
                    eq('competition', competition) 
                    round { 
                            ge('roundNr', startRound.roundNr) 
                    } 
                    or { 
                            round { 
                                    le('roundNr', currentRound.roundNr) 
                            } 
                            gt('state', Game.STATE_NOT_STARTED) 
                    } 
                    order 'date', 'asc' 
            }     

      def sortGames = games.asList().sort(games.round.sorting)
```

The query works fine, i want to sort them.

Error:

```
   Error 500: Executing action [recalcCompetitionTable] of controller [at.ligaportal.CompetitionController] caused exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.sort() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 14, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16]] Possible solutions: sort(), sort(java.util.Comparator), sort(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), size(), size() 
    Servlet: grails 
    URI: /ligaportal/grails/competition/recalcCompetitionTable.dispatch 
    Exception Message: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.sort() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 14, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16]] Possible solutions: sort(), sort(java.util.Comparator), sort(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), size(), size() 
    Caused by: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.sort() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 14, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16]] Possible solutions: sort(), sort(java.util.Comparator), sort(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), size(), size() 
    Class: ApiAuthenticationFilter 
    At Line: [77]
```

where is my Problem?

I got the Games via withCriteria() method, sort by date.

And all games have rounds , and now i want to sort them by the sorting of the rounds.

5 Games have 1 Round and alle Games have dates.

```
Round 1 = 18.09.2012 - 25.09.2012 (5 Games)
Round 2 = 26.09.2012 - 31.09.2012 (4 Games) and one Game plays later 
5.11.2012
Round 3 = 1.10.2012 - 7.10.2013

And my problem is, i sum up the round with a each and previous round.

Roudn 1 = 3,3,3,1,1 Points
Round 2 = 6,4,4,2,1 Points -> 1 Games later 
Round 3 = 9,7,7,4,3 Pounts
Round 2 = 6,4,4,4,1 (after game)
Round 4 = here i cant go back to round 4 -> the one game is lost!
```

And now i want to order the games via game.round.sorting

This is my problem.

Thank you!

The Solution

```
def bySorting = new Comparator() {
        int compare(a,b) { a.round.sorting <=> b.round.sorting }
    }
    games.sort(bySorting)
```

Comment: what is `games.round.sorting`?

Comment: @joe69, You do sorting twice: first in your query: `order 'date', 'asc'`, and then after it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `sort()`on `games` due to the result of your criteria is already sorted.

Instead sorting by date : `order 'date', 'asc'` you could add your desired property here.

If you really need to sort the result you have to pass an `Comparator` or a `Closure` to `sort()`:

```
def sortGames = games.asList().sort{it.round.sorting}
```

You should provide some more information. Looks like `sorting` is an `ArrayList` - how should the `games` be sorted?

Comment: All Games have Rounds. 2 Models:

Comment: Please edit your question. Add your domains and describe your desired sort criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to sort by round as part of the initial database query by using `createAlias` in your criteria:

```
def games = Game.withCriteria() {
                createAlias('round', 'rnd')

                eq('season', currentSeason) 
                eq('competition', competition) 
                ge('rnd.roundNr', startRound.roundNr) 
                or { 
                        le('rnd.roundNr', currentRound.roundNr) 
                        gt('state', Game.STATE_NOT_STARTED) 
                } 
                order 'rnd.sorting', 'asc' 
        }
```

This way you don't need to do any sorting of the returned list in Groovy.

---

However, if you do want to sort an existing list of games by their `round.sorting` value then you almost had the right syntax.  What you actually need is:

```
def sortGames = games.sort { it.round.sorting }
```

The Groovy sort method expects a *closure* that returns the sort key, whereas your attempt was passing a list of all the sort keys for all the games.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it is not clear what `games.round.sorting` does.

But have a look at the following links to learn more about sorting lists in groovy:
[Custom list sorting](http://www.groovyexamples.org/2010/07/14/custom-sort-a-list/)
[Groovy OrderBy](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/12/groovy-goodness-using-orderby.html)

Or google for `Groovy Comparator` to find other examples and descriptions.